# jquery-ui tabs callback not triggered when tabs are first initialized

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to simulate the `ui.newTab, ui.oldTab` functionality introduced in [jquery-ui 1.9](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).  (Drupal does not yet support 1.9, and so I am using [1.8](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs).)
Here is my simulation code:

```
var oldTab;
var newTab;
mytabs.tabs({ 
  select: function(event, ui) {  
    oldTab = newTab;
    newTab = $(ui.tab); 
    if (oldTab){
      console.log("do stuff with oldTab");              
    }
    console.log("do stuff with newTab);
  }
});
```

When the user clicks on a new tab, this 'select' callback gets triggered.  So far so good.

However, this 'select' callback is not triggered when jquery-ui first initializes the tabs and selects the leftmost tab.  As a result, oldTab is not defined the first time the user clicks on a new tab.

I have tried adding code to programmatically select the leftmost tab:

```
mytabs.tabs('select', 0)
```

But the select callback still does not get triggered.  I believe that is because the leftmost tab is already selected.  See [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tabs-select-index-and-callback-functions)

Any advice on how I can initialize newTab to the selected tab, when jquery-ui initializes the tabs and selects the leftmost tab?

Comment: It is because the first tab is not selected, it is activated as part of the widget initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the first tab is not selected, it is activated as part of the widget initialization, which does not trigger the select event.

One possible solution is to set the initialization value for `oldTab` as part of declaration.

```
var oldTab;
var newTab = mytabs.find('> ul a:first');
mytabs.tabs({ 
  select: function(event, ui) {  
    oldTab = newTab;
    newTab = $(ui.tab); 
    if (oldTab){
      console.log("do stuff with oldTab",oldTab.get());              
    }
    console.log("do stuff with newTab", newTab.get());
  }
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HceFxZjiCM8aQoaBUYs0?p=preview)